# Authlogic - return user to intended page after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

How can you adapt a standard Authlogic app so instead of the home page every time, it directs a user to whatever link they were trying to get to?

**Example 1** - standard log in works as expected

```
User goes to app.com
Goes through 'login' process
Redirected to home_url
```

**Example 2** - user attempts to visit a specific page

```
User goes to app.com/specific_link
Redirected to login_url for authentication
Expects to be sent back to /special_link; instead sent to home_url
```

How can I return the user to the link they want in Example 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the page when you go to login, then used that to return the user to that page after login, e.g.

```
# redirect to the login page. Call this in the login action, when successful.
def redirect_away(*params)
  session[:original_uri] = request.request_uri
  redirect_to(*params)
end

# returns to the original url from a redirect_away or to a default url
def redirect_back(*params)
  uri = session[:original_uri]
  session[:original_uri] = nil
  if uri
    redirect_to uri
  else
    redirect_to(*params)
  end
end
```

Comment: I just realized I was missing the second part of this code in my user_sessions_controller. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Michael was close, but there is no "request_uri" method for the request object.

Murifox was also close, but #referrer does not give you the information you want. You probably want #url.

Try this (assumes "authenticated" returns your logged in status):

```
before_filter :check_authentication
.
.
.
private

def check_authentication
  unless authenticated
    session[:intented_page] = request.url
    redirect_to login_page
  end
end
```

Then in the controller that handles logins, after a successful login in you just do:

```
redirect_to session[:intended_page]
```

Incidentally: the #referrer method was originally mis-spelled as #referer. Now there is an alias so both spellings work, but "referrer" is proper according to the dictionary.

(Edited later): Actually #referrer might be what you want. If you are IN the controller for the target url when you check your authentication (as in the code here) then you want #url. If you are in a controller where you've been redirected **from** the target controller, then you want the #referrer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `request.referer` holds this information for you. So you check for the existence of this attribute on the `request` object, and if it exists, you redirect to it, instead of the `home_url`.

```
if request.referer
  redirect_to request.referer
else
  redirect_to home_url
end
```

Something like this.

Comment: Be careful when using the referrer. Imagine a user being redirected to a login page. If they have to make more than one attempt at entering their password, you'll lose the original referrer.

Answer (score 0):

While the above suggestions will work use of session is not the best option cookies have a maximum size of 4,096 bytes. This is not much and if your mixing what could be a rather long URL could cause your session store to fail.

You should use the cookies method instead. This will create a separate unencrypted(by default) cookie keeping your session data separate.

```
cookies[:original_uri] = { value: request.request_uri, expires: 10.minutes.from_now }
```

Then to read the cookie you use

```
cookies[:original_uri]
```